macOS React Native .xcode.env.local node path not being correctly assigned
.xcode.env
# This `.xcode.env` file is versioned and is used to source the environment
# used when running script phases inside Xcode.
# To customize your local environment, you can create an `.xcode.env.local`
# file that is not versioned.

# NODE_BINARY variable contains the PATH to the node executable.
#
# Customize the NODE_BINARY variable here.
# For example, to use nvm with brew, add the following line
# . "$(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh" --no-use
export NODE_BINARY=$(command -v node)

We have a react native project. Our node installation is managed with asdf-vm. When I run the command as a user command -v node and which node I get the correct path returned to me as follows:
> which node
/Users/devboi/.asdf/shims/node
> command -v node
/Users/devboi/.asdf/shims/node

But when run the same commands as a yarn script
"scripts": {
    "nodePath": "which node",
    "nodepath": "command -v node"
  },

➜ yarn nodePath
/private/var/folders/gs/hrtylh996mv147w1xqzdm2fm0000gn/T/xfs-407a6ad6/node

➜ yarn nodepath
/private/var/folders/gs/hrtylh996mv147w1xqzdm2fm0000gn/T/xfs-5833b283/node

The reason I ask about this is that when we generate our .xcode.env.local from the config set up by the .xcode.env file the temporary paths with private are the ones being written to the .xcode.env.local files. I have seen people using nvm has run into the same issues, but I haven't seen any clear solutions.
What am I missing? Some config of yarn? Or an export somewhere?

I had an issue when trying to run the project, I have node installed via asdf, and I would always get a "could not find path node" when running the project. Are you facing this error when trying to run the app? or is it just the issue when running the script? I was able to fix the issue by running this command sudo ln -s "$(which node)" /System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/bin

it's a problem when I run the project on mac. It sets the path to one of the /private/xyz/ strings in .xcode.env.local because it either lacks the permissions to read the folder or yarn have no idea what that command means.

Try replacing the /private/xyz/ path inside of xcode.env.local to the result you get when running which node or command -v node

Also which react-native version are you on?

we are running 0.75.3 - we have replaced the string manually in the .env.local file and it works. It just seems like that should not be necessary imo

Yeah, it I feel like it is unnecessary as well. In our project we were using 0.74.3 which apparently had an issue causing the path to node to fallback to the default node path. However, they mentioned that they solved this in a 0.75.x release. Can't find the issue to link it. But anyway, glad that it is resolved.

While running package scripts, Yarn generates a wrapper in the TMP directory in order to inject node as a script into your PATH. This ensures any node processes spawned while running package scripts use the same instance of node that Yarn itself is running on.
To get the actual path of that node instance, try
"scripts": {
  "path": "node -p 'process.execPath'"
}

